# In Azure DevOps, is there a way to export the details of the execution history of test points?

Tags: azure-devops

Our client is asking if there's a way for us to provide them a list of testers who have executed test points in DevOps. I saw that each test point would have execution history. If there's a way to export those details (please see attached screenshot), that would really help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can bulk export Test Cases from a Test Suite like the following:
[image]

Link: https://www.ecanarys.com/Blogs/ArticleID/415/Bulk-Export-Import-Test-Cases-to-Azure-DevOps-Test-Plans-using-CSV-file

Comment: I'm aware of that feature. Though it doesn't contain details like "Run By" and other details from the Execution History of the screenshot I showed.